# Django is changing the order of my Integer List

Tags: python, django, list, arraylist, retrofit

So I'm facing the following problem.

When creating a List of Integers in Android Studio:

```
List<Integer> myIDs= new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm putting the integers (id's) in a given order, with a result of, p.e:

```
myIds = [69, 65, 67]
```

I'm using **Retrofit** for sending the request to the server:

```
@POST("looks/")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Look> createLook(
        @Field("myIds") List<Integer> myIds, 
        ...,
        ...);



mAPIService.createLook(myIDs, ..., ...).enqueue(new Callback<Look>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Look> call, Response<Look> response) {

                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("OK: ", "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());
                            // We finish the Activity.
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            ...
                            ...
                        }
                        finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Look> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

The problem is that when I'm sending the List to my django server it is ordering it by itself to:

```
"myIds ": [
        65,
        67,
        69
    ]
```

Any idea on why is that happening, and how could I solve it?

On the server, this is my models.py

```
...
myIds = models.ManyToManyField('garments.Garment')
...
```

views.py

```
class LookList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = LookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Look.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username',None)
        date = self.request.query_params.get('date', None)
        if date is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date=date)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username=username)
        return queryset


class LookDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Look.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LookSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class LookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Look
        fields = ('id','garment_id','username','date')
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You omit some steps in your process of saving the ID's. What kind of API do you use? Can you show the requests being made?

Comment: @Jieter edited OP with more info! I'm using Retrofit, and I also show the request

Comment: The view listinging at the url your posting to is especially interesting.

Comment: @Jieter there you go!

Comment: I suggest making requests to your django app using curl or [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). In that way you can learn what side of the interaction is responsible for the misordering.